# Issue with Stale data Flask/SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn, supervisord

I have the following set up for which on session.query() SqlAlchemy returns stale data:

Web application running on Flask with Gunicorn + supervisor.
one of the services is composed in this way:

- app.py:

  ```
  @app.route('/api/generatepoinvoice', methods=["POST"])
  @auth.login_required
  def generate_po_invoice():
  try:
     po_id = request.json['po_id']
     email = request.json['email']
     return jsonify(response=POInvoiceGenerator.get_invoice(po_id, email))
  except Exception as ex:
      app.logger.error("generate_po_invoice(): " + ex.message)
  ```

in another folder i have the database related stuff:

DatabaseModels (folder)

|-->Model.py

|-->Connection.py

that's what is contained in the connection.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(DB_BASE_URI, isolation_level="READ COMMITTED")
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
```

and thats an extract of the model.py file:

```
from DatabaseModels.Connection import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, etc...

class Po(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'PLC_PO'

    id = Column("POId", Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column("POCode", String(50))
    etc...
```

Then i have another file POInvoiceGenerator.py
 that contains the call to the database for fetching some data:

```
import DatabaseModels.Connection as connection
import DatabaseModels.model as model
def get_invoice(po_code, email):
    try:
        po_code = po_code.strip()
        PLCConnection.session.expire_all()
        po = connection.session.query(model.Po).filter(model.Po.code == po_code).first()

    except Exception as ex:
        logger.error("get_invoice(): " + ex.message)
```

in subsequent users calls to this service sometimes i start to get errors like: could not find data in the db for that specific code and so on. Like if the data are stale and so on.

My first approach was to add isolation_level="READ COMMITTED" to the engine declaration and then to create a scoped session, but the stale data reading keeps appening.

Is there anyone that had any idea if my setup is wrong (the session and the model are reused among multiple methods and files)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please cleary add the errors message you have, showing the error line number and SQLAlchemy log if available. Also, if you really want to catch Exception, try to display the class of it. It could be better to catch first sqlachemy NoResultFound and StaleDataError, which will show you specific error.

Comment: There is no actual error in SqlAlchemy, is just that the data that i get from the db are outdated, in the sense that has been modified externally and already committed in the db, but when called from python, the data are kinda read from the memory of SqlAlchemy

Comment: "the data are kinda read from the memory of SqlAlchemy" : if you first "read from database" and then do not change anything from an instance, subsequent reading will be read from "memory" : this IS the way SqlAlchemy is running.
Please show us some log of the error, to better understand your problem. In code you show, there is no modification at all, so data can not be stale ... unless you have another computing process which change database while your Flask app is running.

Comment: "unless you have another computing process which changes database while your Flask app is running." - unfortunately, this is what is happening, The flask app is reading from a database that can be modified externally from the flask app itself, is a db shared by various processes.

Comment: Web are stateless/transactionless. If you want to deal with the same data you use on previous state/transaction, you must ensure it. For example here first catch NoResultFound (from sqlalchemy, using query.one() rather than query.first() ). Then, use for example optimistic locking to know if data has been changed elsewhere (look at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/versioning.html#mapper-version-counter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even if the [solution](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/versioning.html#mapper-version-counter) pointed by @TonyMountax seems valid and made me discover something that i didn't know about SqlAlchemy, In the end i opted for something different.

I figured out that the connection established by SqlAlchemy was durable since it was created from a pool of connection everytime, this somehow was causing the data to be stale.

i added a NullPool to my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

engine = create_engine(DB_URI, isolation_level="READ COMMITTED", poolclass=NullPool)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session = Session()
```

and then i'm calling a session close for every query that i make:

```
session.query("some query..")
session.close()
```

this will cause SqlAlchemy to create a new connection every time and get fresh data from the db.

Hope that this is the correct way to use it and that might be useful to someone else.

Comment: You should look at Flask after_request / before_request where you could put your code to open/close a session. Then you just have to place query in your code, and forget the close() which will be called in after_request each time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm exploring this way as well, having to rewrite the same code always is not the best thing ever.

Answer (score 0):

The way you instantiate your database connections means that they are reused for the next request, and they have some state left from the previous request. SQLAlchemy uses a concept of sessions to interact with the database, so that your data does not abruptly change in a single request even if you happen to perform the same query twice. This makes sense when you are using the ORM query features. For instance, if you were to query `len(User.friendlist)` twice during the same session, but a friend request was accepted during the request, then it will still show the same number in both locations.

To fix this, you must set up the session on first request, then you must tear it down when the request is finished. To do so is not trivial, but there is a well-established project that does it already: [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/). It's from Pallets, the people behind Flask itself and Jinja2.